# Fazer consultas usando o entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Dentro do meu repositorioEF eu tenho os métodos, no método `ExcluirRegistro` eu estou passando uma `StatusRegistro` para o banco que indica que este registro está sendo excluído, então nos meus métodos `ListarPorId` e `ListarTodos` eu gostaria de trazer apenas os registros com `STATUS` diferente de ‘S’. Como eu poderia fazer estas consultas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Projeto.Financeiro.Dominio;
using Projeto.Financeiro.Dominio.contrato;

namespace Projeto.Financeiro.RepositorioEF
{
    public class EmpresaRepositorioEF : IRepositorio<tb_empresa>
    {

        private readonly Contexto contexto;

        public EmpresaRepositorioEF()
        {
            contexto = new Contexto();
        }

        //salvar ou altera o registro
        public void SalvarRegistro(tb_empresa entidade) 
        {
            if (entidade.IDEMPRESA > 0)
            {
                var empresaAlterar = contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == entidade.IDEMPRESA);
                empresaAlterar.RAZAO_SOCIAL = entidade.RAZAO_SOCIAL;
                empresaAlterar.ENDERECO = entidade.ENDERECO;
                empresaAlterar.BAIRRO = entidade.BAIRRO;
                empresaAlterar.CIDADE = entidade.CIDADE;
                empresaAlterar.IMAGEM_LOGO = entidade.IMAGEM_LOGO;
                empresaAlterar.STATUS = entidade.STATUS;

                //implementar IEntidade nos Models para salvar as datas DATA_ALTERACAO e DATA_INCLUSAO
            }
            else
            {
                contexto.Empresa.Add(entidade);
            }

            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        //excluir o registro
        public void ExcluirRegistro(tb_empresa entidade)
        {
            //não vou excluir o registro, apenas trocar o status para 'S'
            char StatusRegistro = 'S';
            var empresaExcluir = contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == entidade.IDEMPRESA);
            empresaExcluir.STATUS = StatusRegistro;
            //contexto.Set<tb_empresa>().Remove(empresaExcluir);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        //listar por id
        public tb_empresa ListarPorId(string id)
        {
            int idInt;
            Int32.TryParse(id, out idInt);
            var Consulta = contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == idInt);
            return Consulta;
        }

        //listar todos
        public IEnumerable<tb_empresa> ListarTodos()
        {
            return contexto.Empresa;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
    public tb_empresa ListarPorId(string id)
    {
        int idInt;
        Int32.TryParse(id, out idInt);
        var Consulta = contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == idInt && x.STATUS != 'S');
        return Consulta;
    }

    //listar todos
    public IEnumerable<tb_empresa> ListarTodos()
    {
        return contexto.Empresa.Where(e => e.Status != 'S');
    }
```

Comment: Muito bom, sem dúvidas este e o melhor lugar para aprender porque tem pessoas que realmente ajudam a solucionar as dúvidas. Mais uma vez agradeço!